# incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'int *'; dereference with * , what this error mean?

Tags: c

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ary[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int *p = ary + 3;

    printf("%d %d %d %d",*p, p[-2], p, ary );
    printf("%d",&ary)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your are trying to print `p` and `ary` with the `%d` format.

Comment: Which line does cause that message? Did you try to split that line into multiple statements? Which of those is the culprit?

Comment: Please explain the history and reasoning of the shown code? If you wrote it with what purpose? If not, why do you try to compile it?

Comment: `%d` is for printing integers. `p` is a pointer, not an integer. `ary` is an array of integers, not an integer. `&ary` is a pointer to an array of integers, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As sayed before, you are using the wrong printf formater, if you want to print the pointer (address that points by p) - use p which is the conversion specifier to print pointers. see below:
e.g.

```
int var = 0;
printf("%p\n", (void *) &var);

int* p_var= &var;
printf("%p\n", (void *) p_var);
```